# swagger editor generating typescript client that will not POST

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I have generated an Angular2 typescript client with the Swagger Editor located at [http://editor.swagger.io](http://editor.swagger.io/#/). The API works fine with all api endpoints that are not of type `POST`, although POST endpoints never get sent to the server.

The following method in the generated typescript is reached, and the `console.log` statement shows that the headers are being set, although nothing actually POSTs to the server.

This suggests that there is something wrong with the `this.http.request` call.

```
public snapshotsFoo (data: Array<number>, extraHttpRequestParams?: any ) : Observable<models.Snapshot> {
    const path = this.basePath + '/Snapshots/foo';

    let queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
    let headerParams = this.defaultHeaders;
    headerParams.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    // verify required parameter 'data' is not null or undefined
    if (data === null || data === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Required parameter data was null or undefined when calling snapshotsFoo.');
    }
    let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headerParams,
        search: queryParameters
    };
    requestOptions.body = JSON.stringify(data);

    console.log('I am in foo', path, requestOptions);

    return this.http.request(path, requestOptions)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            if (response.status === 204) {
                return undefined;
            } else {
                return response.json();
            }
        });
}
```

I can successfully use the endpoint from the swagger ui (http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/ui), from POSTman, and from the command line with `$ curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '[7,7,8]' 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/Snapshots/foo'`

Although, when I try to reach this endpoint using the generated typescript, nothing is posted to the server and no errors are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the http observable was getting garbage collected before it actually posted (from what I can see).

The broken situation in my component:

```
...
this.snapshotApi.snapshotsFoo([6,7,8]);
...
```

the fixed situation in my component:

```
...
let whocares = this.snapshotApi.snapshotsFoo([6,7,8]);

whocares.subscribe(res => {
    console.log('i dont even');
}
```

Feel free to comment on what the hell is going on. POSTing to my server now works. Observation changes behavior...

Comment: editor.swagger.io leverages generator.swagger.io to generate API clients, server stubs. Please open an issue in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen (which covers the online generator at generator.swagger.io)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, I had inadvertently forgotten to subscribe to my api call. I discovered from the [Rx documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html) that:

> An Observable is called a “cold” Observable if it does not begin to emit items until an observer has subscribed to it; an Observable is called a “hot” Observable if it may begin emitting items at any time, and a subscriber may begin observing the sequence of emitted items at some point after its commencement, missing out on any items emitted previously to the time of the subscription.

In this case the HttpClient returns an observable which allows us to add further actions to the sequence and so is a 'cold' observable, only firing when it is  subscribed to.

Comment: Confused as to why a `GET` request gives a hot Observable and a `POST` gives a cold Observable

Comment: My understaning is that it is the act of subscribing to it that makes it hot